# add_custom_command() not working CMake

Tags: build, cmake

I would like to add custom command so that intermediate files are generated and will be passed on to add_library(). I tried below but it seems to be not working as no moc `cpp` files are created.

```
set( MOCKFILES
  a.h  
  b.h
  c.h)

set(QTMOCEXE ../../../../../../../XXXX/external/Qt/5.5.0/compilers/moc.exe)
set(MOCOPTION -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT
              -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_XML_LIB
              -DADMATERIALUI_LIB -D_WINDLL)

foreach(_file ${MOCKFILES})
    string(LENGTH ${_file} length)
    string(FIND ${_file} "/" FileNameTemp REVERSE)
    string(SUBSTRING ${_file} ${FileNameTemp} ${length} FileName)
    #get_filename_component(${_file} FileName)
    add_custom_command(
        OUTPUT moc_${FileName}.cpp
        COMMAND QTMOCEXE MOCOPTION ${_file} -o moc_${FileName}.cpp
        COMMENT here we go!
        )
endforeach()
```

My idea is to create intermediate moc files (generated from *.h) using qt MOC. I do not want to use the `set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON) set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)`.
I'm newbie to CMake and could not get away with this issue. Could somebody shed some lights on this part. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your question? And more important: What's wrong with automoc? Especially for newbies, they should stick to the path and not trying to work around the mechanisms provided by the tool.

Comment: `add_custom_command` doesn't generate files until some **target** (created with `add_executable`, `add_library` or `add_custom_target`) depends on that files. Add call like `add_executable(my_exe a.cpp b.cpp c.cpp)` and everything will work.